# Save OpenSSL output in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, openssl, output

I'm trying to save the output of a simple OpenSSL command to a variable in Python.

```
$ openssl ciphers 'DEFAULT:!EXP:!LOW:!MEDIUM:!kDH:!kECDH:!DSS:!PSK:!SRP:!kRSA'
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-CAMELLIA256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-CAMELLIA128-SHA
```

In Python, I use `check_output` from `subprocess` to capture the output.

```
from subprocess import check_output
out = check_output(["openssl", "ciphers 'DEFAULT:!EXP:!LOW:!MEDIUM:!kDH:!kECDH:!DSS:!PSK:!SRP:!kRSA'"])
```

This results in:

```
openssl:Error: 'ciphers DEFAULT:!EXP:!LOW:!MEDIUM:!kDH:!kECDH:!DSS:!PSK:!SRP:!kRSA'' is an invalid command.
```

I've tried a variety of things, to resolve this issue.

- Escape the single quotes for the (`\'DEFAULT:!EXP:!LOW:!MEDIUM:!kDH:!kECDH:!DSS:!PSK:!SRP:!kRSA\'`)
- Create variable for the above string and use that in `check_output`
- Separate `ciphers` and the above string in `check_output` (`check_output(["openssl", "ciphers", "..."]`)

None of my attempts worked.

If I separate the `ciphers` and the ciphers string I get the following error.

```
out = check_output(["openssl", "ciphers", "'DEFAULT:!EXP:!LOW:!MEDIUM:!kDH:!kECDH:!DSS:!PSK:!SRP:!kRSA'"])
Error in cipher list
140348600368856:error:140E6118:SSL routines:SSL_CIPHER_PROCESS_RULESTR:invalid command:ssl_ciph.c:1226:
140348600368856:error:140E6118:SSL routines:SSL_CIPHER_PROCESS_RULESTR:invalid command:ssl_ciph.c:1226:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 626, in check_output
    **kwargs).stdout
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 708, in run
    output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['openssl', 'ciphers', "'DEFAULT:!EXP:!LOW:!MEDIUM:!kDH:!kECDH:!DSS:!PSK:!SRP:!kRSA'"]' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

I don't understand why this doesn't work with `check_output` as it does when simply executed in the terminal.

---

**edit:** I've tried an alternative approach with `PIPE` and `run`:

```
>>> from subprocess import PIPE, run
>>> command = ["openssl", "ciphers", "'DEFAULT:!EXP:!LOW:!MEDIUM:!kDH:!kECDH:!DSS:!PSK:!SRP:!kRSA'"]
>>> result = run(command, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
>>> print(result.returncode, result.stdout, result.stderr)
1  Error in cipher list
140088420478680:error:140E6118:SSL routines:SSL_CIPHER_PROCESS_RULESTR:invalid command:ssl_ciph.c:1226:
140088420478680:error:140E6118:SSL routines:SSL_CIPHER_PROCESS_RULESTR:invalid command:ssl_ciph.c:1226:
```

This also results in an "invalid command".

---

> **Q:** How can I capture the output of the mentioned OpenSSL command in Python3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to wrap the cipher list twice.

Try this,

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> out = subprocess.check_output(['openssl', 'ciphers', 'DEFAULT:!EXP:!LOW:!MEDIUM:!kDH:!kECDH:!DSS:!PSK:!SRP:!kRSA'])
>>> out
b'DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA\n'
```

Comment: Great! I just wanted to add a solution on my own, but yours is more elegant. I used `run` with `shell=True`. Thank you!

Comment: @SaAtomic Glad it helped.